# Spark kafka producer Introducing duplicate records during kafka ingestion

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-kafka-integration

I have written a  spark kafka producer, which pulls messages from hive and pushes into kafka, most of the records(messages) are getting duplicated when we ingest into kafka, though i do not have any duplicates before pushing into kafka. I have added configurations related to exactly-once semantics making kafka producer idempotent

below is the code-snippet i am using for kafka producer

```
import java.util.{Properties, UUID}

import org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{KafkaProducer, ProducerConfig, ProducerRecord}
import org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.{AuthorizationException, OutOfOrderSequenceException, ProducerFencedException}
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

object KafkaWriter {

   lazy val log = LogManager.getLogger("KafkaWriter")


   private def writeKafkaWithoutRepartition(df: DataFrame, topic: String, noOfPartitions: Int,
                                            kafkaBootstrapServer: String): Unit = {
      log.info("Inside Method KafkaWriter::writeKafkaWithoutRepartition no of partitions =" + noOfPartitions)
      df.foreachPartition(
         iter => {
            val properties = getKafkaProducerPropertiesForBulkLoad(kafkaBootstrapServer)
            properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis().toString)
            log.info("Inside Method writeKafkaWithoutRepartition:: inside writekafka :: kafka properties ::" + properties)
            val kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](properties)
            try {
               log.info("kafka producer property enable.idempotence ::" + properties.getProperty(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG))

               kafkaProducer.initTransactions
               kafkaProducer.beginTransaction
               log.info("Inside Method writeKafkaWithoutRepartition:: inside each partition kafka transactions started")

               iter.foreach(row => {
                  log.info("Inside Method writeKafkaWithoutRepartition:: inside each iterator record kafka transactions started")
                  kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord(topic, row.getAs[String]("value")))
               })
               kafkaProducer.commitTransaction
               log.info("Inside Method writeKafkaWithoutRepartition:: kafka transactions completed")
            } catch {
               case e@(_: ProducerFencedException ) =>
                  // We can't recover from these exceptions, so our only option is to close the producer and exit.
                  log.error("Exception occured while sending records to kafka ::" + e.getMessage)
                  kafkaProducer.close
               case e: KafkaException =>
                  // For all other exceptions, just abort the transaction and try again.
                  log.error("Exception  occured while sending records to kafka ::" + e.getMessage)
                  kafkaProducer.abortTransaction
               case ex: Exception =>
                  // For all other exceptions, just abort the transaction and try again.
                  log.error("Exception occured while sending records to kafka ::" + ex.getMessage)
                  kafkaProducer.abortTransaction
            } finally {
               kafkaProducer.close
            }

         })
   }

   def writeWithoutRepartition(df: DataFrame, topic: String, noOfPartitions: Int, kafkaBootstrapServer: String): Unit = {
      var repartitionedDF = df.selectExpr("to_json(struct(*)) AS value")
      log.info("Inside KafkaWriter::writeWithoutRepartition ")
      writeKafkaWithoutRepartition(repartitionedDF, topic, noOfPartitions, kafkaBootstrapServer)
   }

   def getKafkaProducerPropertiesForBulkLoad(kafkaBootstrapServer: String): Properties = {
      val properties = new Properties
      properties.setProperty(CommonClientConfigs.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootstrapServer)
      properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
      properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
      properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true")
//      properties.setProperty(CommonClientConfigs.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "400000")
//      properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG, "300000")
      properties.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "1000")
      properties.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all")
      properties.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, "1")
      properties
   }

}
```

set the isolation.level-->Committed on the kafka consumer end.

tried setting min.insync.replicas-->2(In my opinion this property might not play an important role , still tried)
Spark version : 2.3.1
kafka client version : 2.2.1

And I am also using transactions while producing messages into kafka, init begin and commit transactions for each message.I am ingesting around 100 Million records one time, I did split the data into smaller chunks, say 100 Million divided into 1 Million at once before ingesting into kafka

Tried using structured streaming, still no luck

```
df.selectExpr(s""" '${key}' as key """, "to_json(struct(*)) AS value").write.format("kafka").options(getKafkaProducerProperties(topic)).save
```

I am not sure if i am missing any configurations on the kafka producer , broker or at the consumer end.
Not sure if i can include any

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Note: Each Spark executor has its own Producer instance... How many executors are running?

Comment: Around 6 executors are running

Comment: Alright, well, your Kafka-specific properties seem fine, so I suspect there's something that Spark is doing that is duplicating the data across multiple executor tasks